# Why GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS? iPhone 5

Tags: iphone-5

While porting an application from iphone 4s to iPhone 5, I got the error GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS after calling this code:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 1);

glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, 1);

glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, 2);
```

According to the OpenGLES spec the error is caused by "Attachments do not
have the same width and height", but I'm using 1136 x 640 for both color and depth buffer.

The same code runs well on iphone 4s (with 960 x 640 buffers).

Answer (score 2):

Depth and color buffer have diff size.
For get real size color buffer:

```
    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:layer]
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &w);
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &h);
```

Also you need set scale to CAEAGLLayer:

```
    layer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

You can see how it's done in Ogre3D, SDL, Cocos2d-x.